# Como verificar se um arquivo está em uso sem lançar exceção C#

Tags: c#, arquivo, exceção, try-catch

Tenho uma aplicação que processa uma fila de arquivos.

Preciso abrir os arquivos para leitura e escrita.

Por vezes os arquivos encontram-se em uso quando vou processá-los.

Como posso checar se o arquivo está em uso?

Hoje eu trato mais ou menos assim. Criei uma função  :

```
public bool ArquivoEmUso(string caminhoArquivo)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(caminhoArquivo);
        fs.Close();
        return false;
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

E uso assim :

```
if (ArquivoEmUso(@"C:\Teste.txt"))
{
    //Processar depois...
}
else
{
   //Processar agora....
}
```

Funciona usando try{} catch{}, mas gostaria de evitar que ocorresse uma exceção.

Alguém conhece alguma forma de testar se o arquivo está em uso sem que precise ser disparada uma exceção?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

De nada adianta poder verificar se um arquivo está em uso num ambiente de concorrência. Normalmente o que se faz, é tentar executar a operação desejada, e colocar um try/catch em volta da operação com o arquivo... afinal, logo após se fazer a verificação, um outro agente externo pode passar a usar o arquivo.

### Explicação

Ao fazer isso:

```
if (!ArquivoEstaEmUso(nomeArquivo))
{
    // faz alguma operação com o arquivo
}
```

é exatamente o mesmo que isso:

```
var liberado = !ArquivoEstaEmUso(nomeArquivo);
if (liberado)
{
    // faz alguma operação com o arquivo
}
```

Acontece que um agente externo pode bloquear o arquivo entre a atribuição da variável e o `if` que vem logo a seguir:

```
var liberado = !ArquivoEstaEmUso(nomeArquivo); // neste momento não está bloquado!
// o que acontece se o arquivo for bloqueado aqui... exatamente na posição deste comentário?
if (liberado)
{ ...
```

Num ambiente de concorrência, fazer a verificação não adianta, pois o descrito acima pode acontecer... e então você teria de usar um try/catch de qualquer forma.

### Como deveria parecer o seu código

Mesmo com a verificação que você fez no seu código, um dia ele vai falhar, como expliquei anteriormente.

Eu aconselho que seu código fique assim:

```
var caminhoArquivo = filaDeArquivos.Dequeue();
try
{
    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(caminhoArquivo))
    {
        // processar o arquivo agora
    }
}
catch
{
    // colocar o arquivo na fila, para ser processado depois
    filaDeArquivos.Enqueue(caminhoArquivo);
}
```

Onde `filaDeArquivos` poderia ser do tipo `Queue<string>` contendo uma lista dos arquivos que você vai processar.

Answer (score 7):

De acordo com a [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use) de uma pergunta semelhante no stackoverflow.com o jeito é este mesmo que você está utilizando.

A resposta ainda diz que apesar de muitos não acharem confortavel se utilizar de exceções, para esta tarefa elas são o caminho a seguir.

De qualquer forma, é melhor tentar utilizar o arquivo pois a única garantia que você terá que o arquivo não está sendo utilizado por outro processo é se você mesmo obtiver acesso ao o travar enquanto obtem o acesso.

Caso contrário, após checar o arquivo, vamos dizer que ele não estava em uso no momento você verificou, quem iria garantir que no próximo instante isso já não fosse válido?